# _ViewStart.cshtml and _ViewImports.cshtml not being run when embedded

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I've embedded all my views including these files mentioned above, they are in the assembly, but when I run the code these views are not hit, so I can't seem to embed the ViewImports or ViewStart pages, I don't know if it has anything to do with the '_', or something else.

Anybody else experienced this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "embedded"?

Comment: I've embedded them (an all views) in the assemblies using Build Action, U then load the application parts for each assembly during startup, all other views are available, except the _ViewStart.cshtml and _ViewImports.cshtml, which is causing problems with loading the correct layout pagein my _ViewStart.cshtml page

Answer (score 1):

I was being a schmuck...
the page I was trying to go to, where the ViewStart was not running was a ViewComponent,, and a ViewComponent does not behave like a standard View, hence why it wasn't running.
*facepalm*

Answer (score -1):

you must copy from shared folder _ViewImports.cshtml file   and past  in all folder view if you using area in project